# Managing UITableViewCell selected states

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableViewController with a static table view and 2 sections.  The first section has two cells, with a layout Table View Cell > Content View > Text Field.

The second section of table view cells has a layout that is Table View Cell > Content View > Label - and the cells expand when they're selected by using `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and reporting cell heights via `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Right now, when I touch one of the first sections' cells, the keyboard comes up and the cursor is placed in the text field, but the cell is not selected - which means that if I had previously selected one of the cells in the second section, it would remain selected (and therefore expanded).

[image: text field as first responder but other cells selected]

Also, if I have selected a cell in the first section with the text field given first responder, then I select a cell in the second section, the cell expands, but the first cell does not resign first responder and dismiss the keyboard.

Did I layout my table view incorrectly such that the cell selected states are not managed automatically and if not: what is the proper way to manage the selected states of the UITableViewCells?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you have written the code. But from above information I have created one sample application. The code is as below and it is working as you want.

I have considered the table with 2 section.
First section has the textfield on Cell.
Second section has the UIlabel on the cell.
txtFieldCopy is of type UITextField declared in .h of class.

Please check the way I have assigned the Tag to the view as we need it to get the indexpath.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCellStyle style =UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    int iTag=[indexPath row]+1;
    txtFieldCopy=nil;
    if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        UILabel *lblFirst=nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

                lblFirst = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 100,
                                                                     40)] ;

            lblFirst.tag=iTag;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFirst];

            lblFirst=nil;
        }

        lblFirst = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:iTag];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

        lblFirst.text =@"Label 1";
    }
    else
    {
        UITextField *txtFirst=nil;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

                txtFirst = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 50,
                                                                         40)] ;

            txtFirst.tag=iTag;
            txtFirst.delegate=(id)self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:txtFirst];

            txtFirst=nil;
        }

        txtFirst = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:iTag];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

        txtFirst.text =@"text 1";
    }
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(txtFieldCopy)
    {
        [txtFieldCopy resignFirstResponder];
        txtFieldCopy=nil;
    }
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"%d",textField.tag);
    NSIndexPath *iRowId =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(textField.tag-1) inSection:0];
    [tblSample selectRowAtIndexPath:iRowId animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    txtFieldCopy=textField;
}
```

Make sure if suppose in between you are reloading the table view then `txtFieldCopy=nil;` in the cellForRowAtIndexPath get called and set to null. so you can ignore this line. But before please check whether you are calling it again and again.

Let me know if it worked for you or not. I am sure it definitely work for you